# getJSON not working?

Tags: jquery, getjson, jstree

I am rendering a tree in Freemarker using JStree plugin.
I wrote a recursive macro ...which has

```
<a href="#" onClick="myfunc(element)">myfile</a>
```

element is a java object like tree passed by controller to  freemarker template.
each element has some properties like name, and 
 in

```
myFunc(element){
    $.getJSON("element",{data}, function(listdata){ //simplest form -not even called.
        any alert code;
    });
}
```

Now this is my first experience with jquery and jstree and i am already in tears.

Thanks

Comment: There must be a problem with your ­`{data}`. Try using `$.get()` instead of `$.getJSON()` and inside, `alert(listdata);` to see if the returned information is valid `JSON`

Comment: you can check this:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6002325/getjson-not-working

Answer (score 1):

`$.getJSON` does an ajax request where the first parameter is the URL.

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/ - "Load JSON-encoded data from the server using a GET HTTP request."

If you're looking to parse JSON from your DOM you can use `JSON.parse(<string here>)` or if you're looking to get the JSON object of a string you can use `JSON.stringify(<obj here>)`.

http://json.org/js.html

You might also want to open up the dev console in your browser (F12 in IE/Firefox, right-click CTRL+SHIFT+J in Chrome/Safari) and you'll probably see it trying to go to http://element to get the JSON.

Comment: This is to represent elements in a java tree. 
And i saw an example to display files in a folder tree using same.It contains
getJSON("/rootFolder" ,{parentid:parentid},function(data) {....})

I have to do similar thing to render my elements .
But not clear on jsTree usage.I was told i dont need to parse JSON as getJSON does the same.(Googling result -it implicitly calls parseJSON , i remember).

If i am writing wrong parameters- instead of url, data ,please suggest.

Comment: To Kevin's tip , i tried with single quotes too. If thats what he meant .