# Read data from JSON file using JQUERY or javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a big json file it's structure is somewhat like
 json

```
- Lessons
    [{ "1 ":
         { " name ": "abc" ,
           " number ":"123" ,
            "check ":
             { "name ":"abc1" ,
               " quizes" :
                [ { "Questions " :
                     [ { "questiontype ": "your name" ,
                      "questionstem " : "name"
                     " options " :
                        [{ answer : "1",
                         ident : "left",
                         feedback : "yes" , 
                         answer: "no",
                         ident : "yes",
                         feedback : "yes"}
                        { answer
                         ident
                         feedback } 
                       {  answer
                         ident
                         feedback }]
                     correct_answers }}
                 Questions 
                 Questions 
                 Questions 
                 Questions 
                 Questions 
                 Questions 
                 Questions 
                 Questions 
                 Questions ]
         practise
         show
             name
             quizes }
     2 
     3}]
```

Above I am just providing tree of json with some value before this is first time I am reading data from json I don't have any idea how to read it plz give me some hints

Comment: https://www.google.co.in/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ix=seb&ie=UTF-8&ion=1#sclient=psy-ab&hl=en&site=webhp&q=json+parsing+jquery+&oq=json+parsing+jquery+&aq=f&aqi=g-c2g-j2&aql=&gs_nf=1&gs_l=hp.3..0i7l2j0i18l2.7197.14822.0.15034.9.9.0.0.0.0.137.999.0j8.8.0.QVYj-K5ANaw&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.,cf.osb&fp=ba6c205675f97627&ix=seb&ion=1

Comment: This is not a correct Json, plz correct your JSON using http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: this is nor original json i got file it's just copy of that tree

Answer (score 3):

In jQuery you can read json by use `$.parseJSON`

```
​var jsonData = '{"a" : "22"}';
$.parseJSON(jsonData)
```

When use `$.parseJSON`, don't miss to insert Single Quote (') or Double Quote (") in the root of json.

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/oamiamgod/za8DN/) and [Here with json array](http://jsfiddle.net/oamiamgod/za8DN/1/)

And here is a JSON Validator. http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: but hoe can I fetch the data inside it

Comment: From my [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/oamiamgod/za8DN/) you can use `json.a` to get the number 22.

Comment: function parsejson(){

$.getJSON("0132549840.json",function(data){
console.log("Hello");
$.each(data, function(key,value){

});
});
} I tried to did this but I am not able to ptint console statement is their any thing wrong

Comment: Look like you have to use `$.ajax` This post has the same problem. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6002325/getjson-not-working