# Difference between ajax and getJSON calls?

Tags: javascript, json, jquery

I have a page being served from a Web.API app located at `http://server/application`.  On the client side, I am doing a GET to pull some data from the servers.  The problem is what I thought should work does not.

This code works:

```
$.ajax( {
    url: "api/slideid/getdirectories/",
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function ( data ) {
        setPaths( data );
    }
} );
```

But this does not:

```
$.getJSON( "api/slideid/getdirectories/",
    function ( data ) {
        setPaths( data );
    } );
```

In the first example I see in fiddler that the url it is trying to retrieve the data from is `http://server/application/api/slideid/getdirectories`, which is correct.

In the second, it is `http://server/api/slideid/getdirectories`, which is not right.   I was thinking that these two methods of json GET were the same.... but it seems they are not?

Interestingly, BOTH these methods work on my local dev box- it is only on my staging server that one works and the other does not.  IIS settings are identical as far as I can tell- and I dug in pretty good to check.

So I'm wondering why getJSON does not work, when the jQuery [docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) state that getJSON is just shorthand for the .ajax call?

EDIT:  I had put in an explicit version of getJSON hoping to show that they were very similar calls, but the 'real' getJSON call is now there.

Comment: Go to api/slideid/getdirectories/ from the address bar, see what you get.

Comment: First port of call should always be the documentation, not Stack Overflow. See http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/ for correct construction of `getJSON()` call.

Comment: I know that api/slideid/getdirectories doesn't work (as I stated) and I linked the docs to getJSON.  I was assuming (maybe incorrectly) that getJSON("api/slideid/getdirectories", function (data) {}) was equivalent to what I wrote- probably wrong there

Answer (score 6):

You have a wrong implementation of `$.getJSON()` This should be:

```
$.getJSON(url, {data:data}, function(data){
     alert(data);
});
```

where `{data:data}` is optional.

### From the docs:

> This is a shorthand Ajax function, which is equivalent to:

```
$.ajax({
  dataType: "json",
  url: url,
  data: data,
  success: success
});
```

Comment: My bad- please see the updated question- the syntax is correct, but the problem remains.

Answer (score 0):

```
  $.getJSON(url, {data:data}, ....
```

wrong syntax

Comment: Apologies, question is still the same, but see the updated edit

Comment: @Nicros see here once http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6002325/getjson-not-working