# JQuery get() or getJSON only work for local files

Tags: jquery, get, getjson

I'm tring to load a test.json file from my server. The index.html which trys to load that file is on another server(infact its a local file).

```
$url = 'test.json';    
$.getJSON($url, function(data) {
    for (var i = 0, len = data.length; i < len; i++) {
             //some code
    }
});
```

works perfect.
but when i set `$url = 'http://simonappelt.de/test.json'` it doesn't do anything.
I also tried the get() function to get files from my server but they seam to load nothing.

Thanks Simon

Comment: *"it doesn't do anything"* I highly doubt that. Did you check the console? you should be seeing a very descriptive error.

Comment: possible duplicate of [$.getJSON not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6002325/getjson-not-working)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically you can only make an AJAX request (which is what `$.getJSON` is) on the same domain and protocol as your script. If you wish to make a cross-domain request, you will must use the [JSON-P support of $.getJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/#jsonp), and wrap the data in a callback invocation server side, determined by the query string parameter, `?callback`.

Answer (score 1):

From the [jQuery $.getJSON documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/)....

> Due to browser security restrictions, most "Ajax" requests are subject
>   to the same origin policy; the request can not successfully retrieve
>   data from a different domain, subdomain, or protocol.

Answer (score 1):

Ajax requests can only be made to the same domain as the current document. The ajax url should be a local one. Can read more about this at http://www.webreference.com/programming/javascript/understanding-ajax/index.html.