# how to use jQuery ajax to fetch json data via https POST method?

Tags: jquery, ajax, https

I want to use jQuery ajax method to validate login, the web service is provided by third-party via https POST method.

I use the following code, but it doesn't work.

```
$.ajax({
type: "POST",

dataType: 'json',
contentType:'application/json',
url: "https://salesforce login web service",
crossDomain:true,
data: {un:"bohan",pw:"123456"},
success: function(data) {
alert('success!'); // or not!
},
error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
            alert(xhr.status+" : "+thrownError); // 0

        }
});
```

I think it may be caused by AJAX cross-domain related issue. How can I do with it? who can give me some suggestions? thank you so much.

Comment: DUPLICATE: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18190713/jquery-get-or-getjson-only-work-for-local-files/18190796#18190796

Comment: use jsonp as datatype

Comment: If you have abandoned this question, please delete it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Due to browser security restrictions, most "Ajax" requests are subject
>   to the same origin policy; the request can not successfully retrieve
>   data from a different domain, subdomain, or **protocol**.