# Fetch data from openweathermap.org using getJSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, api, weather-api

I am trying to fetch data from openweathermap.org using the jQuery function getJSON but there is some problem

```js
var apiKey = "54df40e238084fbf095d3540271e48a0";
var URL = "api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London&appid=" + apiKey;

$(document).ready(function() {

  $.getJSON(URL, function(data) {
    console.log(data);
  })


});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Hi, can you please clarify the question? what is the problem?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [$.getJSON not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6002325/getjson-not-working)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The url is wrong, You need to do something like this.

```
var apiKey = "54df40e238084fbf095d3540271e48a0";
var URL = "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London&appid="+apiKey;

$(document).ready(function(){

$.getJSON(URL,function(data){
    console.log(data);
})
});
```

Hope this helps.